# Counting unique combinations of values in 1 column and 2 additional columns without duplicates

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr

I have a large df of genomic data for many different tumor samples. One column "mutation" reports the specific variant of a protein detected in the sample. Two additional columns "allele1" and "allele2" report the HLA-type associated with each sample (each sample will have two values for HLA because it there are two copies of this in the genome). I would like to generate a count of samples with unique combinations of "mutation" and "allele1" OR "allele2" without counting duplicates (i.e. if a sample contained "mutation" mut1, allele1" a2 and "allele2" a2, it should be counted only once).

```
    df <- data.frame(mutation = c("mut1", "mut1"), allele1 = c("a1", "a2"), allele2 = c("a2", "a2"))

mutation allele1 allele2
mut1     a1      a2
mut1     a2      a2
```

I know I can use ddply in the following way:

```
qualities <- c("mutation", "allele1")
countedCombos <- ddply(df, qualities, nrow)
```

But how can I add a third column ("allele2") to my qualities parameter that is joined in an OR fashion to "allele1"? Running two separate analyses with "mutation" and "allele1" then "allele2" and then summing the counts doesn't work because for samples that have the same value for "allele1" and "allele2", they will be double counted.

Hope this is clear, tried to make it as generalizable as possible.

Thanks in advance!

My expected output for the sample data would be

```
df_count <- data.frame(mutation = c("mut1", "mut1"), allele = c("a1", "a2"), count = c(1, 2))

mutation allele count
mut1     a1     1
mut1     a2     2
```

Edit:
Thanks for the help, unfortunately both of these solutions still seem to double count samples with the same allele1 and allele2 values. For example, enlarging the dataset and then recounting

```
df <- data.frame(mutation = c("mut1", "mut1", "mut1", "mut2"), allele1 = c("a1", "a2", "a2", "a2"), allele2 = c("a2", "a2", "a2", "a2"))  

> df
  mutation allele1 allele2
1     mut1      a1      a2
2     mut1      a2      a2
3     mut1      a2      a2
4     mut2      a2      a2


df %>%    
pivot_longer(-mutation) %>%    
distinct() %>%    
count(mutation, value)

# A tibble: 3 × 3
  mutation value     n
  <chr>    <chr> <int>
1 mut1     a1        1
2 mut1     a2        2
3 mut2     a2        2
```

However, my desired output would be:

```
# Desired output:
  mutation value     n
  <chr>    <chr> <int>
1 mut1     a1        1
2 mut1     a2        2
3 mut2     a2        1
```

Comment: please provide sample data

Comment: For your sample data, please provide your expected output

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for editing your question to include the desired output - that makes more sense - here is one potential solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(mutation = c("mut1", "mut1"),
                 allele1 = c("a1", "a2"),
                 allele2 = c("a2", "a2"))

df_count <- data.frame(mutation = c("mut1", "mut1"),
                       allele = c("a1", "a2"),
                       count = c(1, 2))

df_count
#>   mutation allele count
#> 1     mut1     a1     1
#> 2     mut1     a2     2

df %>%
  pivot_longer(-mutation, values_to = "allele") %>%
  distinct() %>%
  group_by(mutation, allele) %>%
  tally(name = "count")
#> # A tibble: 2 × 3
#> # Groups:   mutation [1]
#>   mutation allele count
#>   <chr>    <chr>  <int>
#> 1 mut1     a1         1
#> 2 mut1     a2         2
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Apologies, I modified the post to include the expected output (mut1/a1 combination with a count of 1, mut1/a2 combination with a count of 2). I may not be fully understanding your proposal, but I don't think those two approaches do the trick.

Comment: I think this is very close to what is required. `df %>% pivot_longer(-mutation) %>% distinct() %>% count(mutation, value)` should give the required output?

Comment: Thanks @neilfws, I think you're right, do you want to make that an answer so I can upvote it?

Answer (score 1):

I think Jared did most of the work, but this small alteration generates the output shown in the question:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-mutation) %>% 
  distinct() %>% 
  count(mutation, value)
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 2 × 3
  mutation value     n
  <chr>    <chr> <int>
1 mut1     a1        1
2 mut1     a2        2
```

Comment: Thanks to both you and @jared_mamrot for your help...initially I thought this was working as intended but I think I'm still missing something. Edited the post as above, hopefully I'm explaining well.

Comment: You can get your new desired result using just `df %>% count(mutation, allele1)`. I think you need to consider your logic for counting alleles. Is allele2 even relevant? If it is, perhaps the way you want to count doesn't quite make sense.